# Memory Leak - identify using profiler

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a c# TCP Server application. Each client connection creates a new thread. The thread performs its tasks and gets garbage collected.

When I look in the task manager the memory column ('Memory - Working Set') increases with every client call/ thread creation and never does down even when the thread has completed its task.

I ran the .netmemProfiler. Looking at the 'Real Time' tab, I see that the memory goes to zero as my thread has completed its task

[image]

Please note in the above screen shot, the first two objects are my thread classes. After completing their task they always remain in the profiler but with 0 bytes. The last created thread always has 'Live Instance' and 28 bytes but as soon as new client is created, the bytes of all old threads goes to 0

Please note all code is managed and is .net code written in c#

Should I be worried about task manager?

Comment: This is a bit of a shot in the dark, but I think the .NET profiler only tracks .NET objects; if you have objects that contain unmanaged data (basically `IDisposable`s, i.e. Images and such), you must take care to `.Dispose()` of them correctly.

Comment: All code is managed and is .net code

Comment: Well, stress test your app, then? Shoot as many requests as you can at it as fast as you can and see if it eats up all of your system's memory. If it does, then yes, be worried. :)

Comment: Also, try a memory profiler tool such as https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/

Comment: @user2837961 Visual Studio's own Diagnostic Tools in `Debug > Windows` shows real-time memory usage, allows you to take and compare memory snapshots. I suspect you'll find you are creating a *lot* of temporary objects, eg by using `String.Split`, `+=` or adding items to a List and causing a lot of reallocations. Each time a list's buffer is full a new one is allocated and everything copied over. You can avoid that by passing the `capacity` parameter and preallocate a large-enough buffer

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I agree that I am going string manipulations but should be automatically garbage collected when the thread finishes?

Comment: @user2837961 no, they are collected when the GC runs. Until then they take up RAM. Even with the GC though, creating a lot of temporary strings means a *lot* of allocations, a lot of memory scanning and a lot of cleaning. Using a regex on the other hand can provide a 10x speedup simply because no allocations are involved

Comment: @user2837961 btw that's one of the reasons people are so obsessed with low or no-allocation coding lately, and excited by Span<T> and Pipelines in .NET Core and the full framework. Especially in .NET Core it provides string manipulation methods that *don't* create new temp objects.

Comment: @user2837961 it doesn't even require any special coding to reduce memory consumption. Looping over an IEnumerable when you can, for example, instead of copying it to an array with `ToArray()` means you can process records as they arrive instead of buffering them. The same goes for DataTable and other collections that have to be loaded entirely before they become useful. Writing directly to the output stream instead of eg copying to a buffer or MemoryStream (which is just a wrapped buffer) is another way to avoid buffering

Comment: @user2837961 another technique is to reuse buffers. When you need `byte[]` buffers, you can use the BufferManager or ArrayPool class to reuse ready-made buffers instead of creating and discarding them all the time.

Comment: How do you create the connection (show us the code) and how do you close the connection (show us the code). Btw. on thread per connection isn't a good design.

Comment: Thanks for all very valuable comments. I shall change code to remove all allocations(where possible) and go for a stress test to test memory is GCed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have been stress testing my application. My findings are that the Virtual Memory goes down constantly and finally crashes. I don't think increasing Virtual Memory is an alternative. Is there any way to find why would the Virtual Memory go down? Why is GC not collecting? Any tools you can suggest?